# relation many to many with three table in UML

Tags: many-to-many, uml, associations, class-diagram, junction-table

I have three tables : `tableA`, `tableB` and `tableC`. My question is: Is it possible to have many-to-many relation between these tables and create a table whose name is `tableA_tableB_tableC` in UML ?

Comment: You are probably looking for "ternary association"

Comment: You can do a lot of funny things. The question back is: what for?

Comment: Do you want to create a class diagram showing one class for every table you have? In that case, you draw four classes and you draw an association to tableA_tableB_tableC from each of the other tables. Or do you want to create a class diagram on a more conceptual level, showing only classes for tableA, tableB and tableC, while tableA_tableB_tableC is represented by an association? In that case, you case choose either a ternary association (seldom used) or an association class.

Comment: Tables don't exist in UML, so your question is a bit nonsense as it is now. If you want to ask about classes, then please update your question.